# CRC checksum calculation algorithm

Tags: crc, crc16

Can anyone with good knowledge of CRC calculation verify that this code

https://github.com/psvanstrom/esphome-p1reader/blob/main/p1reader.h#L120

is actually calculating crc according to this description?

CRC is a CRC16 value calculated over the preceding characters in the data message (from
“/” to “!” using the polynomial: x16+x15+x2
+1). CRC16 uses no XOR in, no XOR out and is
computed with least significant bit first. The value is represented as 4 hexadecimal characters (MSB first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the linked code about where it starts and ends, and how the result is eventually represented, but yes, that code implements that specification.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! Yes further down in the same code on line 270 and 278 crc16_update is called to calculate crc. If CRC  is ok then it i s published to the HomeAssistant , line 302 in the code.